# Particular php logic to remove "li" borders by adding a span class to the last li's

Tags: php

I have a simple for loop which displays li elements.

```
for($rn = 1; $rn <= $total; $rn++){
 echo '<li>this is a li element</li>';

}
```

The $total represents how many li's there are.

The li's are floated left, showing 6 li's per row, each li having a bottom border.

I want, using php to remove the border from the li's in the last row by adding a span class.

This is a bit tricky because lets say I have 15 rows.

I need a php code that will substract 12 from 15 and add the no border class to the last 3 li's.

**My idea:** is to divide $total to 6 and round up the result.
15:6 = 2.5
Round up but keeping the smaller value in mind - would be 2.

Ten multiply 2 by 6 and substract 12 from 15, resulting 3 rows.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: What if the last row is full (e.g. if you have 18 `li`s)?

Comment: The reason I ask is that for any number that divides equally, you'll end up with a bottom border for whole of the bottom row instead of no border which is, I assume, what you require.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator `%` yields the remainder from dividing two numbers.

```
15 % 6 == 3
$totalRows % $itemsPerRow
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
for($rn = 1, $end = ( 0 == ( $temp = $total % 6) ? $total - 6 : $total - $temp ); $rn <= $total; $rn++) {
    if ($end < $rn) {
        // no border
    }
}
```

Basically it checks whether it can be divided by 6. If there is no rest, the last six elements get no border. If there is a rest, only the elements that are in the last row get no border.

The advantage is, it doesn't invoke any variables outside the loop.

The loop is untested, the calculation is tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$remainder = $total % 6; // Get your remainder, number of li on the last row.

for($rn = 1; $rn <= $total; $rn++){
    // If the the total minus the number of li's output is less than or equal to remainder your outputting the last row.
    if($total - $rn <= $remainder) 
    {
        echo '<li class=\'borderless\'>this is a li element</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li>this is a li element</li>';
    }
}
```

- Please note this is untested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bottom = $total % 6;
$bottom = $bottom ? $total - $bottom : $total - 6;//calculate values in the last row
for($rn = 1; $rn <= $total; $rn++){
    $class =  $rn > $bottom ? ' class="span"' : '';//if rn is in the last row add span calss
    echo "<li$class>this is a li element</li>";

}
```